# Find the matrix with given kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find one matrix $A\in M_{3,4}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\mathrm{Ker}(A)=\mathrm{L}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
> 3\\ 
> 1\\ 
> 0\\ 
> 0
> \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
> -2\\ 
> 0\\ 
> -6\\ 
> 0
> \end{bmatrix}\right)$ and then describe all matrices with this properity.

What I tried to do so far is the following:
Let $\mathrm{Ker}(A)=V$. Then $V^{\perp }$ can be determined with the system:$$\begin{matrix}
3x_1 & + x_2 & =0,\\ 
 -2x_1& - 6x_3 & =0.
\end{matrix}$$
Now, since $V=(V^{\perp })^{\perp }$, I find that the system that has $V$ as its set of solution is the system:
$$\begin{matrix}
3x_1-9x_2-x_3=0, &  & \\ 
x_{4}=0, &  & 
\end{matrix}$$so one matrix is:$A=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -9 & -1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &0 
\end{bmatrix}$.

My question is how can I describe all matrices that have $V$ as its kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows of your matrix should span the complement $V^\perp$. So if you take a basis for $V^\perp$, like $\{(3,-9,-1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$, than every row vector should be a linear combination of these two. Hence every row is of the form $(3a,-9a,-a,b)$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.